# htaccess rewrite rule extension with slash error

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

**I** have removed my url extension(.php) using htaccess, even made url with extension .php redirect to 404 error, like if my url is www.example.com/page/ and some one adds .php extension at the end like www.example.com/page.php the page redirects as it should
but the problem is when I open the url: "www.example.com/page.php/" with the extension and the slash it opens. No redirection, nothing. I want that to redirect to 404.

Kindly review my htaccess contents and suggest me improvements, if needed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

## non-www to www

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^example.com [nocase]
RewriteRule ^(.*)         http://www.example.com/$1 [last,redirect=301]
```

## index page to only domain

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index/
RewriteRule ^index/$ http://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]
```

## removes extension and adds slash

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

## removes multiple slashes

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=""
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\s//+(.*)\sHTTP/[0-9.]+$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\s(.*/)/+\sHTTP/[0-9.]+$
RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}/%1 [R=404,L]
```

Comment: Above code to remove extension and add slash has some error in the adding slash part...the code works for files within 2-3 child folders and after that the it returns a 404 error..kindly correct the code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a new rule just below `www` rule to remove `.php` extensions:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?/)?(?:index)?(.*?)\.php[\s?/] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1%2 [R=302,L,NE]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I just changed the R=302 to 404 and achieved what I wanted. Thanks again for your help.. Keep helping others. Love you always. One more thing I want to ask you. Should I keep my code for removing multiple slashes. I mean I haven't seen it in use much. Is there any problem with it or is OK?

Comment: You're welcome. You can keep multiple slash removal code but yes that will be very rarely used.